# Laravel Notification Store Additional ID Fields

Tags: php, laravel, notifications, laravel-5.7

So I have Laravel Notifications setup and it's working perfectly fine.

However, I've extend the migration to include an additional id field:

```
$table->integer('project_id')->unsigned()->nullable()->index();
```

Thing is, I don't see how I can actually set that `project_id` field. My notification looks like this:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications\Project;

use App\Models\Project;
use App\Notifications\Notification;

class ReadyNotification extends Notification
{
    protected $project;

    public function __construct(Project $project)
    {
        $this->project = $project;
    }

    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            'project_id' => $this->project->id,
            'name' => $this->project->full_name,
            'updated_at' => $this->project->updated_at,
            'action' => 'project-ready'
        ];
    }
}
```

So ya, I can store it in the data, but what if I want to clear the notification specifically by "project" instead of by "user" or by "notification".

For instance if they delete the project, I want the notifications for it cleared, but there is no way to access that unless I do some wild card search on the `data` column.

So is there anyway to insert that `project_id` in the notification ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create an Observer to update the field automatically.

**NotificationObserver.php**

```php
namespace App\Observers;

class NotificationObserver
{
    public function creating($notification)
    {
        $notification->project_id = $notification->data['project_id'] ?? 0;
    }
}
```

**EventServiceProvider.php**

```php
use App\Observers\NotificationObserver;
use Illuminate\Notifications\DatabaseNotification;

class EventServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
    public function boot()
    {
        parent::boot();

        DatabaseNotification::observe(NotificationObserver::class);
    }
}
```

And you should be able to access the table using the default model to perform actions.

```php
DatabaseNotification::where('project_id', 11)->delete();
```